# Flash works in Chrome Safari Firefox but not in IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a flash movie on the home page of this site http://cbcking.org/.

It displays fine in any browser I test except ie9.

Have searched whatever I know to search and am stumped. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peeping at your web page source code, you have this:

```
    if(document.getElementById('myFlashContent')){
        swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "8.0.0", "/_swf/expressInstall.swf");
    }
```

If I am not wrong, that piece of code is load it up before "myFlashContent" element is loaded, try to change that code to this:

```
$( function() {
   swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "8.0.0", "/_swf/expressInstall.swf");
} );
```

Comment: all the code in that file is already wrapped in a document.ready, I don't think that's the issue?

Comment: Well I was wrong. Moved the call registerObject to the bottom of the html and it works properly in IE. Thanks for the help.